# Keyword argument aliases in Python

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I am creating a custom 3D space from scratch for some new coders, and I am worried that perhaps my documentation isn't beginner friendly. Here is an example:

```py
def make_point(**kwargs):
   X, Y, Z = 0, 0, 0;
   if "Xcoord" in kwargs.keys(): X = kwargs["Xcoord"];
   if "Ycoord" in kwargs.keys(): Y = kwargs["Ycoord"];
   if "Zcoord" in kwargs.keys(): Z = kwargs["Zcoord"];
   return tuple(X, Y, Z);
```

But the way I named the `keyword arguments` isn't very suitable for a new programmer with some knowledge in *`linear algebra`*, but it is necessary for me to keep track which variable is what. So in that manner I have **`vXcoord`** for the vector x coordinate, **`pXcoord`** for point, etc.

Is there a way to make `keyword arguments` more user friendly so if a user typed `vX`,`vectorX` or whatever it seems more logical it would still map to `vXcoord`?

Comment: FWIW: `return kwargs.get('Xcoord', 0), kwargs.get('Ycoord', 0), kwargs.get('Zcoord', 0)`…

Comment: Good point.But still you would need to check if string is present in keys. But yeah :D Get has an solid value that has an default returning. It is optional, but works! :D

Comment: Even your "checking in keys" should be done via `'Xcoords' in kwargs`. But this is exactly the use case for `.get` with a default argument.

Comment: Either is good, using `__contains__` operator of dictionary, or `__contains__` operator in list it is really matter of style - semantics. In the short run, there is no way to check if something exists but to loop over a iterator. It doesn't matter if `dict` or `list` does it for you.

Comment: Checking the key in a dict is a lot more efficient than checking it in a list. The dict uses key hashing, while the list must be iterated.

Comment: I am going to be honest. Lets leave it at that. "Language war" isn't something that is meant for public comment section below question. I am fully open to discuss it further with you in chat room. However i think this comment section has enough information that users can decide for themselves to choose one or other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The idea:**

The idea is that every class could have a list of aliases to specific attributes so user could (based on class name logic: > point needs x, y, z, name attributes, dog needs breed, name, age, sex attributes and so on) based on its own internal logic to call attributes without need for knowing exactly what attribute name sed attribute have.

**The logic:**

If *function* or *class* has for input some keyword arguments, then I would need minimal list of common words associated with sed argument. Synonyms and idioms can be googled easily, but I would advise against the big list of synonyms, keep it small 2-3 + attribute name. Then all we need is to *map* those aliases to the original attribute since we as codes need to know how to call attribute without calling `getattr(self, someattributestring)`

**Code**:

Chronologically we must first define a function to generate aliases.

```
# Generate aliases for attributes
def generateAliases(*argListNames):

    returningValues = [] # This could be omitted if the user wants to make a generator
    la = returningValues.append # This could be omitted also

    # Dominated argListNames
    argListNames = map(str, argListNames) # For simplicity convert to strings
    argListNames = map(str.lower, argListNames) # For simplicity convert to lower string
    argListNames = list(argListNames) # Back to 'list'

    # Small nameless lambda functions
    getFirstChr = lambda element: element[0] # Getting first character
    conectedJoing = lambda connector, item, args: connecter.join([ item, args if not __isTL__(args) else connecter.join(args) ]) # Generating joined string

    # List of string convertors used to generate aliases
    convertorList = [ lambda x: x, getFirstChr, str.title, str.upper, lambda x: getFirstChr(str.upper(x)) ]

    for item in argListNames:
        ## Since we don't want an alias to repeat itself
        listNoitem = filter(lambda x: x != item, argListNames)
        listNoitem = list(listNoitem)

        la(item) # If returningValues omitted, use the 'yield' statement

        for conversion in convertorList: # #1 keeping up with for loops
            converted = conversion(item)

            for connecter in "_, ".split(","):

                for listItem in listNoitem:

                    for cnvrt in convertorList: # #2 cnvrt is converted second stage: used to convert the whole list of items without the current alias
                        cList = cnvrt(listItem)

                        la(conectedJoing(connecter, converted, cList)) # If returningValues is omitted, use the 'yield' statement


                la(conectedJoing(connecter, converted, listNoitem)) # if returningValues is omitted, use the 'yield' statement

    # If the user wanted to make a generator, omit the next lines
    returningValues = [ x.replace("_", "") if x.endswith("_") else x for x in returningValues ]
    returningValues = sorted(set(returningValues))
    return list(map(str, returningValues))
```

Now we need to map and check those arguments inside a **function** or **class**, so we need some argument parser.

```
## **kwargs argument parser, no error
def argumentParser(ApprovedSequence, **kwargs):

    # ApprovedSequence is supposed to be a dictionary data type with {"original argument": generateAliases(originalArgumentName, somealias, somealias, ...)

    """
        Phrases the keyword arguments,
            for example:     argumentParser(ApprovedSequence, someArgument=somevalue, otherArgument=othervalue ...)
        Then it checks if someArgument is needed by checking in ApprovedSequence if name "someArgument" is found in the sequence:
        If "someArgument" is found in ApprovedSequence, it stores returns the dictionary of DefaultKeys: Values,
            for example: DefaultKey for someArgument: somevalue

        input:
            argumentParser(dict: ApprovedSequence, kwargs)
        returns:
            dictionary of found attributes and their values

        !!important!! kwargs are not case sensitive in this case, so go crazy as long as you get the appropriate keyword!!
        If you don't know what kind of keywords are needed for class,
            just type className.errorAttributeNames().
            For example, point.errorAttributeNames()

    """
    if isinstance(ApprovedSequence, dict):

        di = dict.items # dictionary.values(someDict)
        dk = dict.keys  # dictionary.keys(someDict)

        # Managing the kwargs and approved sequence data
        toLowerStr = lambda el: str(el).lower() # Conversion to lower string
        asingKey = lambda el: [ key for key in dk(ApprovedSequence) if toLowerStr(el) in ApprovedSequence[key] ][0] # Assigning key

        return { asingKey(k):v for k,v in di(kwargs) } # Dictionary comprehension
    else:
        raise TypeError("argumentPhraser function accepts only a dictionary for a ApprovedSequence, aka first item")
        return None
```

**Implementation**

```
def somefunction(**kwargs):
    aliases = {
        "val1": generateAliases("first", "1"),
        "val2": generateAliases("second", "2")
    }
    approved = argumentParser(aliases, **kwargs)

    if "val1" in approved.keys(): val1 = approved["val1"]
    else: val1 = 0 # Setting default value for val1

    if "val2" in approved.keys(): val2 = approved["val2"]
    else: val2 = 1 # Setting default value for val2

    # Do something or your code here

    return val1, val2

# For testing purposes
for x in [ {"first": 1}, {"second": 2, "first": 3}, {"f1": 4, "s2": 5}, {"f_1": 6, "2_s": 7} ]:
    # Displaying inputed variables
    form = ["passed "]
    form += [ "{} as {} ".format(key, value) for key, value in x.items() ]
    # Implementing somefunction
    print("".join(form), somefunction(**x))
```

**Output**

```
python27 -m kwtest
Process started >>>
passed first as 1  (1, 1)
passed second as 2 first as 3  (3, 2)
passed f1 as 4 s2 as 5  (4, 5)
passed 2_s as 7 f_1 as 6  (6, 7)
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 0)

python35 -m kwtest
Process started >>>
passed first as 1  (1, 1)
passed first as 3 second as 2  (3, 2)
passed f1 as 4 s2 as 5  (4, 5)
passed f_1 as 6 2_s as 7  (6, 7)
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 0)
```

If implemented in classes, the process is similar in `__init__`, but `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, and `__delitem__` must be coded so they could search for attribute names in aliases as well. Also, attribute names could be generated with `self.attributes = list(aliases.keys())` or something like that. Default values could be stored in classes with `__kwdefaults__` or '**defaults**' depending on what kind of data your function is using.

This code has been tested on Python 2.7 and Python 3.5 as you can see.

**Further explanation if needed**

You can define aliases within class global attributes or within `__init__`.

Explaining further `__getitem__`:

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
    if item in self.aliases.keys():
         return getattr(self, item)
    if any(item in value for value in self.aliases.values()):
         item = [ key for key in self.aliases.keys() if item in self.aliases[key] ] [0]
         return getattr(self, item)
    if item in range(len(self.aliases.keys())):
         item = list(self.aliases.keys())[item]
         return getattr(self, item)
```

Explaining further `__setitem__`:

```
def __setitem__(self, item, value):
    item = self.__getitem__(self, item)
    # ? must have a `__dict__` method or the class needs to be instanced from an object, like class someclass(object)
    item = [ key for key in vars(self).items() if self[key] == item] [0]
    if item != None:
        setattr(self, item, value)
```